# Can logic like this be written as a one-liner?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I want to do something like check if a an element is assigned to a variable and can therefore generate a buffer or else create a new buffer, like so:

```
if (element) { // may be null or an image / video DOM element
    scratchBoardContext.drawImage(element, 0, 0, width, height);
    this.buffer = scratchBoardContext.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
} else {
    this.buffer = createBlankBuffer(width, height);
}
```

This following code is going to be (completely) wrong, but I was wondering if something similar could be used to shorten the previous logic into a one-liner:

```
this.buffer = scratchBoardContext.drawImage(element, 0, 0, width, height) && scratchBoardContext.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data || createBlankBuffer(width, height);
```

Now "Why would you want to make that a one liner" is a different topic, but I am curious if it can be done because I often see people shorten multi line code into nice short one liners that can still be easily understood.

---

Based on the answers, this is a nice way to format it:

```
this.buffer = (element && scratchBoardContext.drawImage(element, 0, 0, width, height), 
    scratchBoardContext.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data) 
    || createBlankBuffer(width, height);
```

I believe I got that right, might need a tweak. Depending on the environment, this could be preferable, but obviously it's probably better to go with the `if / else` because clarity is better than brevity. For small projects where there a just a few collaborators who like shorter code, maybe this syntax is useful though.

Comment: All javascript code can be put into a single line. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Check out the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *possible*, sure, though since the first block is doing *two* things and the second block is doing *one* thing, you'll have to use the ugly and hard-to-read comma operator:

```
this.buffer = element
  ? (
    scratchBoardContext.drawImage(element, 0, 0, width, height),
    scratchBoardContext.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data
  )
  : createBlankBuffer(width, height)
```

Or, mushed into a single line:

```
this.buffer = element ? ( scratchBoardContext.drawImage(element, 0, 0, width, height), scratchBoardContext.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data ) : createBlankBuffer(width, height);
```

But that's quite unreadable - I prefer the first version, or even better, the `if`/`else` version.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the longer version is the way to go, but now I know some ways to do this kind of thing if I run into other similar scenarios.

Comment: There are definitely places for it, but this situation isn't a good opportunity for it because the first block requires two entirely distinct statements. (It would be different if `scratchBoardContext.drawImage` returned the `scratchBoardContext` itself, allowing chaining, but that's probably not the case, right?) You might think about not trying for one-liners, but trying for a single *statement* that may be spread out over multiple lines, which reduces syntax noise while (sometimes) remaining quite readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator. However, since you have two statements make sure you use the [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) operator

```
this.buffer=(element)?(scratchBoardContext.drawImage(element, 0, 0, width, height), scratchBoardContext.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data): createBlankBuffer(width, height);
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to enclose it in parentheses. The answer has been updated.